# How to extrapolate an object from a photo taken with an iPhone

Tags: image-processing

First off, this may not be the right group, however, it is the closest one I can think of.

I took a few pictures of a computer panel at a known distance, but the angle to a corner would require the use of the 3D Pythagoras theorem (*√(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*) See [Pythagoras theorem in 3D](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/pythagoras-3d.html).

So my questions are thus:

1. What is the first step?
2. Will this be possible instead of measuring EVERYTHING?

Pictures will be attached:

1. [image: Rear Panel - Zoom in to get the exact mm measurement]
2. [image: Rear Panel]
3. [image: Rear Panel]
4. [image: Rear Panel]

Comment: What do you mean by "extrapolate"? Do you mean "construct a 3D model from a series of images"?

Comment: As in determine the measurements of all the objects and then extrude a panel.

Comment: Still not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you want to extract a 2D projection of the surface of the panel so that you can automatically compute all measures from it by providing a reference length?

Comment: It would be easier if your images had more parallax